# Vote count colours different on documentation

Tags: bug, documentation, design

The vote count colours are different between Docs and main site. This is an absolute outrage and makes me **very** uncomfortable.

Main site:

[image]

`color:maroon`

---

Docs:

[image]

`color:red`

---

I'd draw a freehand `red` circle around it to further emphasise this atrocity, but I'm afraid it would simply blend in.

I can't even.... I jus.. Nope.

Comment: I think I have seen this problem raised up by some one some time ago... hmmm.

Comment: What about the green?

Comment: downvotes on Docs are of course more important, so they need to stand out more.

Comment: @rene why would you do that to me when I'm clearly in such a fragile state. Colours mean nothing to me now. I live in a world of black and white :(